# Xcode create attributed Text (Justify) in Editor?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uilabel

Ill try to create a simple Label with Attributed Text and Text-Align: Justify. When ill try to create the label with some Code, it works as expected, but i am unable to create a simple Label in Editor with Attributed Text and Justified Text Alignment. Ill simple change the Type to "Attributed" and set up the Alignment to "Justify". Looks fine in the Preview Window (not on the Label in Storyboard)

[image]

Is this a bug in Xcode, or do i forgot anything here?

I need to create a scrollView with lots of Text, and i dont want to make it Justified with Code if possible to create this (faster) with the editor.

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html

Comment: Edited my Question. Ill tried that what Xcode offers me (Attributed text with Text-Align:Justify) -> but this looks only good in the text-preview, not on the device.

Comment: So i need to add constraints to enable it from the editor? (i am still working with Auto-Layout)